# My "/usr" directory is missing

Tags: desktop-environments

I booted my computer this morning and fount the screen absolutely empty.  No files / folders nil!  Back-in-time automatically dos a backup daily, but failed.  It had a common theme, the problems all addressed the "usr" directory.  I opened a terminal window, did a ls -al and there is no listing of the "usr" directory.  If I hunt around in "search your computer" I am able to find the programs I need, so they are there somewhere.  How may I fix this problem please.

The list of the command is below.

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
├─sda1 ext4         c8f75037-4ac0-4130-bb42-6ea889b84974 /
├─sda2                                                   
├─sda5 swap         8a8d2ac8-34c1-48a6-aec7-b2b0f4f29661 [SWAP]
└─sda6 ext4         c280c62f-d988-4163-9801-1c30afaf8c69 
sdb                                                      
├─sdb1 ntfs         22DB2D983C6EF1EA                     /media/rod/22DB2D983C6E
└─sdb2 ntfs         327FB25D62E5FFA1                     /media/rod/327FB25D62E5
sr0                                                      
sr1
```

Comment: please run `sudo lsblk -f` and paste the result

Comment: Hello George, hope you get the answer I sent.  Not too sure how to go about this.

Comment: P.S. I added it to the original question.   Rod

Comment: I have found where it is.!   It is not in Desktop, but is in desktop.  This sounds silly I know but it has found a new directory.  I have tried to copy the folder to Desktop, it then tells me there is no such folder as desktop, therefore it will not copy.  I thought I might be getting somewhere, but....!

Comment: Lets see whether it's in the desktop, please run this in a terminal and give me the output: `ll /home/$USER/Desktop` and do `cat /etc/fstab` and paste that also

Comment: Hello again George, I tried that and was told there was no such file (Desktop).  What I have done is tried copying desktop to Desktop, all that happened here was desktop copied as a folder in Desktop.   That got me riled so I dragged all my files onto the blank Desktop, they are all there and remain after rebooting.

Comment: I hit enter before, that sent the reply out.  To finish, I will stay with I now have and call out if it plays up again.  Thank you for your tremendous help George, I appreciate all you have done for me.   Kind regards, Rodney Jackson.